# make specific path on Excel POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to make a path that saved in database. 
here's my code.

```
    @RequestMapping("import_excel")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, ? extends Object> import_excel() {
        modelMap.clear();

        try {
            HttpSession session = req.getSession();
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Export");

            Row row1 = sheet.createRow((short) 3);

            row1.createCell(0).setCellValue("Asset Number");
            row1.createCell(1).setCellValue("Asset Barcode");
            row1.createCell(2).setCellValue("Asset Name"); 

            short i = 4;

            Row row2 = sheet.createRow(i++);
            row2.createCell(0).setCellValue(as.getCdas());
            row2.createCell(1).setCellValue(as.getBcd());
            row2.createCell(2).setCellValue(as.getNm());

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(src + "/Export.xls");
            wb.write(fileOut);

            fileOut.close();
            modelMap.put("success", true);
            modelMap.put("rows", obj);
            modelMap.put("count", count);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            modelMap.put("success", false);
            modelMap.put("msg", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return modelMap;
    }
```

I want to make  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(src + "/Export.xls"); 
 with the path I save in db. so If I want to change the path I just change in db. 
I've tried code above but doesnt seems work. 
please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: What's the value of `src`? Is it not what you want?

Comment: @Gagravarr src is the path that I want to call in database.

Comment: Where's the code to talk to your database then? I don't see any JDBC calls or similar... Looks like you've missed out the key part of your code!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that use it programmatically...

use

```
String PathTillProject = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

This will give you the system path one level up to `src` i.e. till your project (I assume your `src` is just within your project directory). For example if your project name is `TestProject` then location or `src` is `TestProject/src`. Now you can use it like:

```
String PathTillProject = System.getProperty("user.dir");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(PathTillProject + "/src/Export.xls");
```

Comment: what is the use of system.getProperty? is that direct to my database?
where I call my mapper?